# Make roc curves like roc.glmnet in R

Tags: r, plot, roc, auc

I am plotting several ROC curves in R to compare various models. In particular, I am checking LASSO, Logistic and Random Forests. However, while LASSO has a dedicated function for that, namely:

```
plot(roc.glmnet(lasso.fit_SUM, newx = x.train.loop, newy=y.train.loop)[[10]])
```

Logistic and RF do not come with such functions.
Now the problem is that I should present pretty ROC curves as the one of LASSO. LASSO ROC curve appears like this:

[image]

while Random Forest (and Logistic) like this:

[image]

This is the code I am adopting:

```
  df_train_logit_rf_class=df_train_logit_rf
  df_test_rf_class=df_test_rf
  df_train_logit_rf_class$export_future=as.factor(df_train_logit_rf_class$export_future)
  df_test_rf_class$export_future=as.factor(df_test_rf$export_future)
  
  rf.fit_SUM_classification <- randomForest(formula = export_future ~ ., data = df_train_logit_rf_class, ntree = 500, maxnodes= 100, norm.votes = F) 
  rf.pred_SUM_db <- as.data.frame(predict(rf.fit_SUM_classification, df_test_rf_class, type = "prob"))
  
  rf.pred_SUM_db$predict <- names(rf.pred_SUM_db)[1:2][apply(rf.pred_SUM_db[,1:2], 1, which.max)]
  rf.pred_SUM_db$observed <- df_test_rf_class$export_future
  #head(rf.pred_SUM_db)
  
  # 1 ROC curve
  roc.curve <- roc(ifelse(rf.pred_SUM_db$observed==1, 1, 0), as.numeric(rf.pred_SUM_db$predict))
  plot(roc.curve, col = "gray60")
```

but the outcome is the ugly ROC curve I showed you before.
`export_future` is a factor variable taking either 0 or 1. There are many covariates (mainly interaction term, dummies).

My aim is to plot a ROC curve for RandomForest (and possibly Logistic) which looks like the one of LASSO.

It seems like logistic is just taking a value as threshold (-Inf) and then interpolate the rest of the curve, while it should take more thresholds.

Thank you in advance,

Federico

Comment: You are calling a function `roc` which is not from base R and not from `glmnet` and not from `randomForest`. Your sample code is missing some package loading. In any case, you can use the `pROC` package for this (passing additional arguments for the plotting). It might also be however that your model is predicting only 3 unique values.

Comment: actually, `roc` is a command from pROC: page 69 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/pROC.pdf